# Cannot log in with created user in mysql

Tags: mysql, users, permissions

Using this command

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* to brian@'%' identified by 'password';
```

I try to login with:

```
 mysql -u brian -ppassword
```

The error is:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'brian'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I am doing this as root and I did try to flush privileges.

I tried this with countless users but it does not seem to work. I can create a user with no password and login works. Command line and from phpmyadmin

Comment: Do they show that you've added them? SELECT * from mysql.user;

Comment: They do show up in that select.

Answer (score 4):

You need to explicitly add user@localhost. '%' does not match localhost.

Comment: Are you sure? The documentation indicates that '%' will match any hostname http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/account-names.html

Comment: Yes. localhost has special meaning in mysql it means you are connecting via the local socket.  '%' matches any host arriving via a TCP connection. localhost is not the same as 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Try changing the command you are using to "sql -u brian -ppassword --host=127.0.0.1"

Comment: It's bitten us at work before. Add user@localhost should work.

Answer (score 1):

You definatly used

```
... identified by 'password';
```

and not

```
... identified by password 'password';
```

as the latter expects a password hash value rather than the plaintext password. This would explain why you're unable to login with any of the passwords you set.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do it in 2 commands:

```
CREATE USER 'user1'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass1';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'user1'@'localhost';
```

Doesn't usually give me any trouble

Answer (score 0):

Anything different happen if you specify the host?

`mysql -ubrian -ppassword -hlocalhost`

`mysql -ubrian -ppassword -h127.0.0.1`

Try checking:

`SELECT user, host, password, PASSWORD('password') FROM mysql.user`

And make sure the password in the db and the result of the PASSWORD function are the same?

Answer (score 0):

No network connection is made when you do:

```
mysql -u brian -ppassword # with no -h
```

Instead, a socket connection is made. Socket connects do not match the host wildcard '%'. They only match the host 'localhost' as a security measure. You can force a network connection like this:

```
mysql -u brian -ppassword -h `hostname`
```

That works most of the time, but I have seen a few systems where it did not. If it works for you, it is a good way to avoid maintaining pairs of grants for each user ('user'@'%' and 'user'@'localhost')

Answer (score 0):

The wildcard hostname is only matching TCP connections, not the socket connection used by localhost; you'll need an entry for % and for localhost.

The reason it's working without a password is probably because you have different credentials set in ~/.my.cnf

Comment: James: My first reaction on reading your note of Mar 15 was "Get out of here! If that were true, I'd know it!" Wrong. I didn't know it, and you've just educated me to something I can't believe I'd not already known. I've run into the problem before a couple times, and every time, I appear to have accidentally solved it, by doing what you suggested above, but not understanding why I had to do so. Thanks very much for the wisdom.